# connect my raspbery-pi to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, apache, raspberry-pi

Yesterday, I installed an apche web server and phpmyadmin on my raspberry-py. How can I connect my raspberry-pi to databases in phpmyadmin with python? Can I use MySQL? Thank, I hope you understand my question and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear. But from my understanding, here is what you should try doing: (Note: I am assuming you want to connect your Pi to a database to collect data and store in an IoT based application)

1. Get a server. Any Basic server would do. I recommend DigitalOcean or AWS LightSail. They have usable servers for just $5 per month. I recommend Ubuntu 16.04 for ease of use.
2. SSH into the server with your terminal with the IP address you got when you created the server
3. Install Apache, MySQL, Python, PHPMyAdmin on the server.
4. Write your web application in any language/framework you want.
5. Deploy it and write a separate program to make HTTP calls to the said web server.

MySQL is the Database server. Python is the language that is used to execute any instructions. PHPMyAdmin is the interface to view MySQL Databases and Tables. Apache is the webserver that serves the application you have written to deal with requests.

I strongly recommend understanding the basics of Client-Server model of computing over HTTP.

Alternatively, you could also use the approach of Using a DataBase-as-a-service from any popular cloud service provider(Eg., AWS RDS), to make calls directly into the DB.